# Identifying relationships within a database

Tags: database-design

I am currently designing a database for a made up engineering company for a university assignment.

The engineering company wins a CONTRACT for a certain PROJECT. Therefore the CONTRACT is the parent of the PROJECT.

I have a table CONTRACT which at the minute has it's primary key CONTRACT_ID, I have placed an identifying relationship between CONTRACT and PROJECT so within MySQL workbench adds CONTRACT_ID as part of the PROJECT primary key. I understand to this point.

Next a PROJECT has a BUDGET_SHEET. I believe this would then be a identifying relationship as without PROJECT there is no BUDGET_SHEET so again MySQL workbench automatically creates the primary key which contains (BUDGET_SHEET_ID, PROJECT_ID, CONTRACT_ID).

My question: Is there any need for CONTRACT_ID to be in the BUDGET_SHEET table? There is no need for it there i would have thought? I am interested into hearing peoples views on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a contract_id in the budget_sheet table I would have thought. There is already a link between the project and the contract and project and budget sheet so you could get to the contract information if needed via those relationships.